# Navier Stokes (Equation weak solutions)

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, fluid-dynamics

I just started to learn about the weak solutions to Navier Stokes equations especially the compressible non-Newtonian fluids.

Which books are good to study for it?

Thanks in advance for your guidance.